# Unresolved external symbol C++

Tags: c++, class, symbols

I ahve a problem with a code below:

**ProgrammSettings.h**

```
#pragma once
static class ProgrammSettings
{
public:
    static int fd;
};
```

**Settings.cpp**

```
#include "ProgrammSettings.h"

static bool LoadSettings()
{
    ProgrammSettings::fd = 2; // here error Unresolved symbol!!
    return true;
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike instance variables that require only a declaration, static member variabs of the class must also be *defined*.

Currently, your code contains only a declaration. Add a *definition* of your static `fd` variable to a cpp file to fix the error:

```
int ProgrammSettings::fd;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following line to the start of your cpp file

```
 int ProgrammSettings::fd;
```

Answer (score 1):

Static data members declarations in the class declaration are not definition of them
You have forgot to add the definition to match your declaration of `fd`.
You must explicitly define your class's static data members.